# How do I return a different node if the first node doesn't exist in an XPath Query?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'd like to return a secondary node name if the first doesn't exist, for example:
`return xpath_query("/root/(blue|red)");
// return /root/blue, or /root/red if it doesn't exist`

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:** Yes.

That's a valid XPath 2.0 expression:

```
/root/(blue|red)
```

**Meaning**: `blue` and `red` children of `root` root element.

If you want one **or** the other if that doesn't exist, you could rely on document order like:

```
/root/(blue|red)[1]
```

Or to be more explicit like:

```
/root/(if (blue) then blue else red)
```

XPath 1.0 translations:

```
/root/*[self::blue|self::red]

/root/*[self::blue|self::red][1]

/root/*[self::blue|self::red[not(../blue)]]
```

Comment: When I try `/colors/(blue|red)[1]/description` I get this error: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I'm using Xpath 1.0. Bummer.

Comment: @Tom: Probably you have an XPath 1.0 engine. Try those XPath 1.0 expressions.

Comment: I get the same error when I try `/colors/[self:blue|self:red]/description`. Hmm

Comment: Great, works. If I want to select blue if it exists, and fall back to red only when blue doesn't exist, is your 3rd XPath 1.0 example the most concise way to do it? Thanks

Comment: @Tom: You are welcome. And yes, I think is the most concise XPath 1.0 only expression.