# Why does my XPath query return the default node when the node I want exists?

Tags: xpath

I have the following XPath 1.0 query:

`/root/Nodes/*[self::CustomNode[not(../DefaultNode)]|self::DefaultNode]/Name`

As I understand it, this will return `/root/Nodes/CustomNode/Name` if it exists, or `/root/Nodes/DefaultNode/Name` if it's not found. However, `/root/Nodes/DefaultNode/Name` is being returned even when `/root/Nodes/CustomNode/Name` is present. Any ideas how I can fix this?

`DefaultNode` nodes always proceed `CustomNode` nodes in the document order.

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How do I return a different node if the first node doesn't exist in an XPath Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292135/how-do-i-return-a-different-node-if-the-first-node-doesnt-exist-in-an-xpath-quer)

Comment: Your assumption is wrong because you have inverted the condition from my previus answer. If you want `CustomNode` or `DefaultNode` when the former doesn't exist, you should use this predicate `[self::CustomNode|self::DefaultNode[not(../CustomNode)]]`

Comment: I see. That was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking the vertical line (|) works like an OR?

Here's the details: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp

| Computes two node-sets:
   //book | //cd   Returns a node-set with all book and cd elements

Semantics:
It returns nodes that meet condition A OR condition B.
It returns nodes that meet condition A AND nodes that meet condition B.

Comment: I see. I replaced the pipe with 'or', but it's still returning the default node. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do note that the expression is inside a predicate. The effective boolean value of a node set is true unless it's empty.